# Limit HTML Content Based on Its Size

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a file (basically text) with a large amount of content, and I need to display it using HTML.

The thing is, I don't need to display all of it, only part of it.  The amount that needs to be displayed is unknown.  What **is** known is the size that the content will take up on the screen.  So let's say, for example, the file contains 50,000 words.  I want a screen size that's, say, 8 1/2 x 11 inches (whether I use absolute units or relative to the screen resolution is not relevant).  So, in the HTML, I want to display the first x number of words from the text, such that it takes up exactly one page, not more, and not less.

Is there a way to dynamically determine the size the text will take up, and then only display the amount that takes up the amount of space I want?

All variables are known ahead of time, including page size, font size, spacing--everything.  The only thing that's not known is how much content can fit within a finite, predetermined amount of space.

I think this question is somewhat unique, in that most HTML questions involve changing the formatting based on the content, whereas here, I'm looking to change the content based on the formatting.

I'm open to any client-side methods incluing jQuery or something else, and/or any server side methods (preferably ASP.NET).

Thanks,

Comment: You can not stop the user from changing to zoom factor/font size after it is rendered.  Why not go for a simple `overflow: hidden` as the style?

Comment: @user2310289 or `text-overflow:clip`

Comment: @user2310289, both good ideas, TY.  But I need to know at what point the text stopped.  I will be creating a second page from where the first one left off...

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can calculate it, as there are so many factors involved (and it might depend on the browser).

I would suggest to split the html into paragraphs (cutting the html at an arbitrary character position is usually not a good idea as you'll end up with broken tags). Then you can add the paragraphs one at a time, and check the container's offsetHeight to see if you've gone too far.

Comment: TY.  Doesn't Google Docs have a similar feature?  You can create a doc, with content split into pages.  I can't imagine it's rendered differently in different browsers.  The doc can then be downloaded and opened in MS Word, where each page's content is exactly consistent with how in looked in the browser

Comment: @AYS right, Google Docs is an application, and I can imagine that Google applies some strict, cross-browser formatting rules. And ask Microsoft, they'll tell you how far a doc from Google is from authentic MS Word ;-) Random html content won't have such strict rules, and browser css discrepancies is something Web designers have to live with. The browser thing was more a side comment, the point is that recreating a layout engine is certainly an overkill!

Comment: Actually, this question is part of a greater layout project for in-house use--not a website for the public, so that **is** what I'm trying to do. If my approach is wrong, perhaps you can't point me in the general direction.

Comment: Well, in this case you just need to be aware that this is an ambitious project, as - just like you said - you are trying to recreate the equivalent of Google Docs or Word Online. It seems to me that it'll be easier to control the editing step rather than the rendering step, just like they do.